# Discarding the heading line

Tags: c

I have a .tsv file that I directly input into my code or whatever you say using the "<" after compiling my code that reads the file.
Instead of any fopen I just use scanf throughout my code to read the data lines.
The header is 3 non-double characters that are meant to be read and then thrown away so that I can then put each of the doubles under the 3 columns into separate arrays.

I can't seem to get my code to skip the first line of input from the .tsv file and then go onto actually grabbing the 3 doubles and putting them into 3 separate arrays.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i = 0;
    double X[MAX], Y[MAX], KG[MAX];
    void data_lines();
    while (scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&X[i],&Y[i],&KG[i] )== 3) {
        printf("%lf%lf%lf\n", X[i],Y[i],KG[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", MAX);
    return 0;
}

void 
data_lines() {
    char ch;
    while (scanf("%c",&ch)!=EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n'){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When I output this code, all I get is 999 printed.
So I'm guessing nothing is going into my arrays and the first data line is not being skipped.

Comment: The function _declaration_ (`void data_lines();`) should be placed before the `main` function. And you _call_ the function using `data_lines();` from `main`

Comment: If you added diagnostic printing such as `printf("In data_lines()\n");` at the top of `data_lines()` — or used `printf("In %s()\n",  __func__);` with the same effect — then you'd find that the function is never called, which is why the header is not ignored.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  The posted code is missing many things, including the `#include` statements for the needed header files, the definition of `MAX`,   When the parameters to `main()` are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`.  do Us a favor and delete variables that are not used

Comment: regarding: `void data_lines();`  This is a forward declaration (prototype) for the sub function, not a call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality

Note the forward reference/prototype

Note the way the sub function is called

Note the way the header file: `stdio.h` is included

Note the definition of the value MAX

and now, the proposed code:

```
// the header file needed for the function: scanf() and function: printf() and the value: EOF
#include <stdio.h>

// define a value and give it a meaningful name
#define MAX 50

// prototypes  notice the prototype has 'void' but the actual function has nothing between the parens
void data_lines( void );

// notice the signature when the parameters are not used
int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    double X[MAX], Y[MAX], KG[MAX];

    // call the sub function
    // which returns nothing and has no parameters
    data_lines();

    while (scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&X[i],&Y[i],&KG[i] )== 3) 
    {
        printf("%lf%lf%lf\n", X[i],Y[i],KG[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", MAX);
    return 0;
}


void data_lines() 
{
    char ch;
    while (scanf("%c",&ch)!=EOF) 
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```